# Cant update Customer in woocommerce rest api v2 in Android studio

Tags: java, android, rest, woocommerce, android-volley

When i try to update customer the server return page not found response
Please help me in updating customers 
I using android studio and using volley library

Its working with GET and POST method But not working with PUT and DELETE method

Comment: please post what you tried

Comment: i tried this link: http://aksaya.ir/shopingapp/wp-json/wp/v2/customers/3     and PUT method

Comment: The GET And Post Method Working , DELETE and PUT not working and return page not found

Comment: which HTTP verb are you using?

Comment: PUT Method For update

Comment: try this url http://aksaya.ir/shopingapp/wp-json/wc/v2/customers/3

Comment: The endpoint route for wordpress like /wp/v2/ and woocommerce /wc/v2

Comment: @tamil-selvan-c It's not working

Comment: Response code, please

Comment: 404 - Page Not Found

Comment: I think this is permalink issue. Login wordpress and go to settings->permalink and  save the button

Comment: what should I do with permalink?

Comment: just click save changes. May its solves the issue

Comment: No , nothing changed

Comment: in .htaccess add these https://gist.github.com/umidjons/9107445

Comment: what i would add in .htaccess ???

Comment: `<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>`

Comment: it does not work, i should restart some thing???

Comment: I think may firewall block PUT and DELETE Request or in wordpress, some restriction may written. I checked your URL in postman, it returns 404, but my local REST API (PUT wp-json/wp/v2/comments/1) return 401 Unauthorized. So something wrong in wordpress/server side.

Comment: no the .taccess  fixed my problem thanks  a lot

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `.htaccess` file to make a `wordpress` server allows you to use `PUT` and `POST` methods